# Present a ImagePickerController from a Delegate class to MainViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a simple TableViewController (MainTableViewController).
The delegate and data source methods are in a separate swift file (TableViewService).

Class Signature:

```
class TableViewService: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, LocationObserver {
```

In the delegate method

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

I want to present an ImagePickerController

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("\(indexPath)")
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let  imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = cameraService

            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
                imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            }
            else {
                imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            }
            present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil) <-- here is the problem
        }
    }
```

This does not work because the TableViewService inherits from NSObject, not from a UIViewController class. I want to present this ImagePickerController on my MainTableViewController, but how can i do this.

Things i tried so far:

- Made the TableView Service inherits from UIViewController

`-> Error message: This ViewController is not in the View hierarchy.`

- Tried to pass an instance of the MainTableViewController to the TableViewService, access that instance and call the `present` method on this instance... but this is bad practice and also results i a `Bad access` Error.

How can i present the imagePickerController?

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks is advance.

EDIT:

passing the current instance to the `TableViewService`

```
class NewReportTableViewController: UITableViewController, LocationObserver{

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let locationService = LocationService()

    let tableViewService = TableViewService()
    let headerTitle = ["Bild", " Kategorie", "Kommentar", "Standort", "Datum"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        tableViewService.nrtVC = self
        tableViewService.headerArray = headerTitle

        tableView.delegate = tableViewService
        tableView.dataSource = tableViewService
...
```

Definition in the `TableViewService` to hold the current instance of the `NewReportTableViewController`

```
class TableViewService: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, LocationObserver {
    var headerArray = [String]()
    var contentData = ["Kein Foto ausgewählt", "Bitte wählen...", "Kommentar schreiben...", "", ""]

    weak var nrtVC = NewReportTableViewController()

    let cameraService = CameraService()

    //MARK: - TableView DataSource

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
...
```

Even if I delete the weak i get this `Bad access` error.

Comment: `TableViewService` should NOT be `UITableViewDelegate`, set it to view controller that displays table view

Comment: Try this 
"class TableViewService: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, LocationObserver, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate { "

Comment: passing MainTableViewController should work, just be careful how you pass it and use weak references. As Lu_ said you can move the delegate or create a new delegate which can be called. Something which is a good practice from VIPER is to have one class which is called "router" and he has the knowledge for the navigation.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @Lu_ As soon as i set the `TableViewService` to `UIViewController` i get an error: `Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x109800800> on <NewCityLife.TableViewService: 0x1035167f0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: @m1sh0 Good point to pass an instance of the MainTableViewController to the `TableViewService` but i always run into `Bad access`error. Do you have a code example?

Comment: I don't have an example, but maybe you can show what you are doing, how you create an instance of  TableViewService and how you passing MainTableViewController to it.

Comment: I edit my code in a minute to provide more information. In my Project the MainTableViewController is called `NewReportsTableViewController`. This is where the tableView belongs to. The `TableViewService`is only the delegate and dataSource holder

Comment: You can post a Notification Center from didSelect and then present the image picker controller from NewsReportTableVC or you can get the top visible view controller and then try presenting the image picker controller ?

Comment: Guys i did it! I solved it by using Callbacks. I think NotificationCenter should also work, but i think this callback solution is a bit smarter. If anybody want to know how i solved it, leave me a comment. Thank you guys